# Downside covariance?

Tags: probability

Is there a notion of downside covariance? And if there is, then I presume that downside covariance plus upside covariance is NOT covariance? If I define the downside covariance (is there an alternative definition?):

$$\displaystyle{Cov_d(X,Y) = \iint (X-\mu_x)(Y-\mu_y)f_{XY}(x,y)\mathbb{1}_{\{ (X<\mu_x)\cap(Y<\mu_y)\}}dx dy}$$

and I define the upside covariance as:

$$\displaystyle{Cov_u(X,Y) = \iint (X-\mu_x)(Y-\mu_y)f_{XY}(x,y)\mathbb{1}_{\{ (X>\mu_x)\cap(Y>\mu_y)\}}dx dy}$$

Do those definitions make sense, are they the standard defintions? And the reason for why the sum of those two does not equal to the usual covariance I think is because we are missing the cases when $X \leq \mu_x$ and $Y \geq \mu_y$ and the reverse. Is this correct?

Comment: I am not familiar with them. Yes we are missing the cases you mention, but actually with $\leq$ and $\geq$. That can play a part by discrete distribution.

Comment: correct, let me fix that

Comment: Well done, good and faithful servant! haha :)

Comment: You can get a proper double integral sign using `\iint`.

Comment: In this book (http://tinyurl.com/ybl83pdu, p.88), the author defines says that "it should be evident from [his] definition that upside and downside covariance are straightforwardly additive. In other words, overall covariance is the sum of upside and downside covariance." This seems to be the case when the condition you mention does not apply?